# ClassCastException from subtype to supertype (in scala)

Tags: java, scala, classcastexception, lagom

We are encountering a strange error consistently only on one dev machine, for others it works fine (personally I cannot reproduce the issue):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to scala.collection.Seq
    at scala.Option.map (Option.scala:163)
    at com.lightbend.lagom.maven.RunAllMojo.$anonfun$execute$15 (ServiceMojos.scala:402)
```

`Seq` is a linear supertype of `::` (`$colon$colon`) per https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/immutable/$colon$colon.html. We use Lagom 1.6.0-M2 for Java DSLs, with Scala 2.12. Java version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.212.04.2 (build 1.8.0_212-b04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.212.04.2 (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)
```

It happens during lagom dev-server bootstrap. Purging and redownloading the maven repo (especially scala-lang and lagom deps) did not solve this problem, so this might not be due to a corrupted file.

I diffed the scala jars on my machine with the ones on the bad machine, and they were the same.

What could cause a ClassCastException from a subtype to supertype, where should we start to investigate this issue?

Comment: Could be jdk related. Are they the same?

Comment: yeah we use the same (Amazon Corretto's)

Comment: Do the stack trace gives more information under the lines you pasted?

Comment: not really, just generic maven mojo stuff

Comment: you could try to check maven dependencies between the two to see if there is a difference that could explain the error

Comment: Another option is that these classes are loaded with different classloaders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a classloader issue as [Alexey said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57479086/classcastexception-from-subtype-to-supertype-in-scala#comment101439466_57479086).

The core problem was that a maven plugin used the `<extensions>true</extensions>` config, which messed up the classloaders somehow.

The actual issue was fixed, removing the extension flag solved the problem:

https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/java-lang-classcastexception-scala-collection-immutable-colon-colon-cannot-be-cast-to-scala-collection-seq-during-runall/4821/3